# Xcode Command + / add comment after indentation

Tags: xcode, ide, text-editor

Currently in Xcode when hitting `Command + /` it comments out that line by adding `//` at the **very** beginning of the line. Whereas with other text editors (ex. Atom) it respects the line indentation and puts `//` with a space right before the actual code, and after the white space.

Is there a way in Xcode to change this behavior to put the `//` after the initial white space for the given line?